# Don't display 0 Values

Tags: php, sql

I have two questions in one. I have a php page that display's tables and colomns. Some of the values in member_id is 0 i do not want to display anything that has 0 in it. All the other values do have a value between 1 and infinity as this gets assigned by primary key.

My code is as follow but when i say hidden = 0 it displays noting at all even the ones with the values inside it

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM e_track_access_log WHERE hidden = 0 ORDER BY    
datetime_accessed");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>MSISDN</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
echo "<td><font color=red>" . $row['msisdn'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['datetime_accessed'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['member_id'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The second question is I need to display the latest date and time on top of this echo. Is there also a way to state how many rows it can display as it is displaying all the rows in the table now. i would like to display max 20 rows only the latest 20 rows from SQL

Comment: Ok i found my problem
"SELECT * FROM e_track_access_log WHERE member_id>0 ORDER BY datetime_accessed"

Now it is just the part to show the newest on top. This is my date and time format 2013-03-08 17:18:26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer:

```
    where member_id != 0 AND hidden = 0
```

Second answer:

```
    select * 
    from e_track_access_log               
    where hidden = 0 AND member_id != 0   # filter
    order by datetime_accessed DESC       # the newest is first, the oldest ist last
    limit 0,20                            # show the first 20 row from result
```

Displays the 20 last inserted rows.